# make "Navigator.push" in Future returns

Tags: dart, flutter

I tried to create a "Future" function that returns the "Navigator.push" class instead of "Widget".

I tried the normal method but it didn't work, the current script is like this:

```
...

return new FutureBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(
                    future: fetchUserQR(new http.Client(),snapshot.data), //scan qr code
                    builder: (context1, snapshot1) {
                      if(snapshot1.hasData) {
                          return Navigator.push( //this the problem
...
```

my goal is, when I finish scanning the QR code a new page will appear.

hopefully my explanation can be understood.

thank you, best regards.

Comment: You can use `await` keyword in `Future` function and after that use `Navigator.push`

Comment: thank you for your answer.
can you give me some example @Saman..

Answer (score 3):

You need to return a Widget in the futurebuilder's builder method. So return a Container and after this frame push a new page.

```
return new FutureBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(
                    future: fetchUserQR(new http.Client(),snapshot.data), //scan qr code
                    builder: (context1, snapshot1) {
                      if(snapshot1.hasData) {
                        SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                           // Navigator.push....
                        });
                        return Container();
                      }
//...
```

Comment: I have tried the code you suggested. it works. but the existing page from "_Navigator.pop_" cannot interact and cannot be clicked on, did i do something wrong?

Comment: This seems like a different issue and maybe you should open a different question thread because I am not sure about what you implemented using Navigator.pop. (if this answer was right please mark it as such) :)

Comment: thanks for your answer.
I'll see the problem first.